# How I can wait an async function in my App.vue before mount next component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I have a problem.. In my vue mobile application I need to, in my App.vue get the language of the smartphone to translate the application. But, it's not working well, when I install the application all the variables in the first page are not working like "CHOOSE" ('CHOOSE' is a variable in my I18n) but when I reaload the page I have the good translation.

I know what is going wrong..

In my App.vue I call an async function that serves to store the langcode of the smartphone in my store (vuex).

App.vue :

```
  mounted() {
    this.setLang();
  }
  methods: {
    async setLang() {
      let lang = await this.device.getLanguageCode();
      lang.value != "en" && lang.value != "fr"
        ? this.$store.commit("setLang", "en")
        : this.$store.commit("setLang", lang.value);
    }
  }
```

Notice that the return of this.device.getLanguageCode() is a promise.

How I can wait this response until load the Home.vue which have for route "/" ?

Thank's.

Update :

I'm using i18n as a mixin like this :

```
  computed: {
    getStoreLang() {
      return this.$store.getters.getLang;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.lang = this.getStoreLang();
  },
  methods: {
    __(string) {
      return this.translatedStrinds[string][this.lang] || string;
    },
    setLang(lang) {
      // FR par défaut
      this.lang = this.availableLang[lang] || "fr";
    },
    getLang() {
      return this.lang;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the async/await is a "Fake sync" apearence but in realy is a Async process, you can't wait to finish, all vue enviroment will continue.

But you can use a correct use of Vuex to detect a change of store using getters, when you change a Data using a commit a "call change event" is fire across all getters functions and the change is reactive.

Please read the Vuex documentation and if you want a solution, please write the final propouse of lang variable.

EDIT:

I don't know what are you using for i18n, but i think that vue-i18n can change on hot with location hot changes:

https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/

Comment: I have update my post, I'm a little bit lost to find solution. I know that my store is updated when the promise with my langcode is solve, but how I can refresh the traduction..? For illustration i give you an example : ```        PLAY: {
          fr: "Jouer",
          en: "Play"
        },``` and at the first load, my component home is chowing "PLAY"

Comment: Try use vue-i18n is to easy of use, and have a documentation that help you

Comment: vue add i18n and is install on your project, itself install on vue component and integrate a i18n HelloWorld to look how made i18n

Answer (score 0):

you can use .then and finally

```
  await this.device.getLanguageCode()
   .then(({ data }) => {
     lang.value != "en" && lang.value != "fr"
        ? this.$store.commit("setLang", "en")
        : this.$store.commit("setLang", lang.value);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }).finally(()=>{ 

    });
```